# File Stream Data Clarification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

If at all File stream option is enabled.

Will sp_helpdb show the database size which includes even FileStream Data.
Or only .mdf and .ldf sizes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `sp_helpdb` wont show info about filestream data. You have to use a [custom solution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1629/determine-free-space-consumed-space-and-total-space-allocated-for-sql-server-databases/) modified as per your needs.

Remember that `sys.database_files` with `file type 2 = FILESTREAM` shows data about filestream.

Answer (score 1):

`sp_helpdb` does NOT include the size for FileStream data. You can use [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) to get the size information for FileStream data.